# Автоматическое размещение открывающей скобки на новой линии

Tags: visual-studio-code

Как настроить автоматическое размещение открывающей скобки так, чтобы она располагалась всегда с новой линии?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/32900921/5752652

Comment: Пользуюсь Prettier, ESLint и Beautify. Но в моём случае (JS) не нужно открывать скобку с новой строки, это не по принятым стилям и может вызывать проблемы в некоторых случаях. Для других языков или заложено в расширении языка, или можно настроить через дополнения подобные этим.